# Can't use Indy with Amazon Simple Email Service

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe, indy10

I'm on Delphi XE and Indy version 10.5.7, trying to send emails using Amazon SES, but i always get the exception below :

```
First chance exception at $76734E28. Exception class EIdSocketError with message
'Socket Error # 10060
Connection timed out.'.
Process sendtest.exe (4472)

First chance exception at $76734E28. Exception class EIdException with message 'Reply Code is not valid: p'. Process sendtest.exe (4472)
```

The same code i'm using below, works in an application on Delphi 2007 and Indy version 10.6.1.5188 :

```
  idsmtp1.Host := 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
  idsmtp1.username := 'myusername';
  idsmtp1.password := 'mypassword';
  idsmtp1.Port := 587;
  idsmtp1.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
  idsmtp1.usetls := utUseExplicitTLS;
  idsmtp1.UseEhlo := true;
  with IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1 do
      begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      end;
  idsmtp1.Connect;
  idsmtp1.Send(idmessage1);
```

Comment: Just checking:  You seem to be using an older version of Indy with XE than you did with D2007.  Is that correct, and why, as a matter of interest?

Comment: upgrade your XE indy to the latest version, what is stopping you?

Comment: @whosrdaddy I can't because latest Indy version will conflict with TClientDataSet

Comment: @MartynA Yes, that's correct because latest Indy on Delphi XE will conflict with TClientDataSet and i cannot update

Comment: @delphirules conflict in what way exactly? This is the first time I'm ever hearing of Indy conflicting with `TClientDataSet`

Comment: @delphirules can you please [edit] your question to show the actual code you are using with Indy 10.5.7? There are big differences between 10.5.7 and 10.6.1. The `Reply Code is not valid` error you are seeing tells me your 10.5.7 is not handling the SMTP traffic correctly, but I need to see the exact setup you are using for 10.5.7.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated once and for some reason it conflicted with DBExpress... Somebody even told me if i use DbExpress, i could not update.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The actual code is that, except for the SMTP credentials... I can send you the project source if it helps

Comment: "Somebody even told me if i use DbExpress, i could not update."  If that was in an SO q/a, please post a link to it.  In any case, I suggest you note @RemyLebeau's comment about it.

Comment: @MartynA I will try to locate the question, but i remember clearly that there is an issue, you can't use DBExpress in Delphi XE if you upgrade Indy.

Comment: @delphirules I see nothing wrong with the code shown. I would need to see the raw SMTP traffic that is being transmitted over the underlying socket. Since SSL/TLS is involved, try attaching a `TIdLog...` component to the `TIdSMTP.Intercept` property, such as `TIdLogFile`. As for dbExpress, it has nothing to do with Indy, and vice versa, so updating Indy should not affect dbExpress in any way, AFAIK. Please find that reference that says otherwise. Maybe you are thinking of DataSnap instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, i mean DataSnap, not DbExpress. It this correct ? Can i update Indy and still use Datasnap ?

Comment: @delphirules in D2009-XE, no.  In XE2+, yes.  See [Indy's installation notes](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx).